# How can I call a script which is out of html directory?

Tags: php, url, routes, directory-structure

Here is my directories' structure:

```
/var
   /www
       myscript.php
       /html
           index.php
```

Currently, `index.php` is empty. I want to know, what should I write in it to be able call `myscript.php` script through a *http* request?

Comment: put `myscript.php` file into `html` folder  (-;

Comment: @Neodan maybe their `myscript.php` contains something that shouldn't be accessible/viewed from the public area and that could be "anything". Edit: Am I right on this Martin?

Comment: A: What you need to do is use a full system path "to" that file.

Comment: @Fred-ii- so why he want access to it via url like `http://domain/myscript.php` ? :)

Comment: @Neodan Yeah, that's an issue. I think in either case, they should call their first file as an HTTP request and simply include their file using a full system path. The question is starting to look unclear/too broad at this point and I'm unsure if the OP even read our comments, or doesn't want to be bothered by mere "comments", rather than the answers area where they apppear to be active.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes you're right. Just what's `full system path` ?

Comment: A full system path is: `include '/var/www/myscript.php';` or `include '/var/www/html/file.php';` there are other ways though. @MartinAJ

Comment: @Fred-ii- I see

Comment: @Fred-ii- Just why not `require_once` instead of `include`?

Comment: @MartinAJ I was going to edit my original comment to hold that also, I just didn't have time. The "include" was basically a "basic" example ;-) that could have been `include_once` or `require` or `require_once`, take your pick ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- As a marginal question, do you have a job? Don't want to join to a start-up team as code-reviewer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This usually works :

```
<?php // index.php : url is /html/index.php
include('../myscript.php);
```

In case you want to do the opposite :

```
<?php // myscript.php : url is /myscript.php
include('html/index.php);
```

Comment: And how should the URL look like to select `myscript.php` ?

Comment: He only needs to go up one directory, not two.

Comment: @kainaw right, thanks

Comment: @MartinAJ this code is meant for you to call /html/index.php, I will edit the answer in case you wish to do the opposite.